Audio Playback Issue in UWP Kiosk Mode: Crackling Sound on Application Startup
I'm developing a UWP application intended to run in Kiosk Mode. One of the requirements is to play an audio file on startup, which I've implemented in the OnLaunch method. When I manually start the application, everything works fine. However, when the PC starts in Kiosk mode, there's a crackling effect or sound distortion at the beginning of the application.
I've noticed that adding a delay of around 15 seconds resolves the issue, but I don't consider this an optimal solution. My assumption is that Windows needs time to settle down after startup, and perhaps the audio drivers are not fully initialized yet, though I'm not entirely certain.
Any insights or alternative approaches to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Does this behavior happen on a normal windows device (not in Kiosk Mode)?

@RoyLi-MSFT nope, this only happens in kiosk mode. If we run application manually, there is no issue in sound.

That behavior really looks like the audio drivers are not initialized completely in Kiosk Mode. Is it possible to delay the play of content?

@RoyLi-MSFT, If i add delay of 15 seconds in 'OnLaunch' before playing audio then I am not observing this issue. but I am trying to find better solution then that if there is any.

I'm afraid that this might be the only workaround we could do from the code side.
